# ASP.Net MVC3 Controller Authorize attribute issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Home Controller with these actions:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Logoff()
    {
        HttpContext.Session.Remove("LogonTicket");
        HttpContext.Session.Remove("PID");
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Now, when I logoff using the Logoff Action, I want the Authorize attribute of the Index to take effect but it doesn't when I return the Index View in the Logoff Action.

How would I handle this?

I'm using a custom MembershipProvider and not sure how to put Logoff functionality in it.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing.  The AuthorizeAttribute works with the Asp.NET IPrincipal system, not whatever login ticket system you've created.  You need to provide more information on how your authentication system works.

Comment: As I said, I'm using a custom MembershipProvider and it sets the Session variables in the ValidateUser() function..

Comment: I figured it out. I was unaware that the authentication stuff was running through the AccountController's Login, ValidateUser, and Logoff methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done in the AccountController Logoff Action. They are public "globals" in a base controller now, too.

```
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        LogonTicket = null;
        ParticipantID = null;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should redirect, not return the view directly:

```
public ActionResult Logoff()
{
    HttpContext.Session.Remove("LogonTicket");
    HttpContext.Session.Remove("PID");
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Returning the view directly sends the view's markup to the client right away and the `Authorize` filter does not get invoked at all.

Comment: It is still trying to load partials that shouldn't be loaded if the authorize attribute is being observed.

Comment: Would doing something in the MembershipProvider make this work right?

Comment: I assumed you have already set up your user/membership/role infrastructure. If not, you first have to do the plumbing. For an inspiration, take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers

Comment: Yes see my comment above. I figured out what I needed to do.